# should i move to Angular 2 RC 5 or wait for it to be stable?

Tags: angular

I'm still at angular 2 beta7 with my human machine interface, i'm a little bit afraid that it will take me a lot of time to upgrade it to RC5, because in the changelog there are a lot of changes, does anyone have an advice to give me ?? in the case you'll say i need to upgrade do you have some shortcut to change directly what i need to change and update my full project to the RC5 ? thank's in advance

Comment: Hello, this is an opinion question, not very suitable for StackOverflow, but I think that after RC5, there won't be too many changes anymore

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAlHamali That's what I told myself about RC0.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on a very old version, I suggest you slowly move to RC version, like RC5, there are many differences between RC and beta versions.

You'll have to make the jump anyway when the final version is released. And the jump will be big, so why not start early?

Comment: thank's for your answer, do you have some shortcut upgrading tutorial ? i have a large project so there are really lot of changes i need to do i would appreciate some help

Comment: I think you could start upgrading your components but keep the old router, `@angular/router-deprecated` and leave it as a last step to upgrade

Answer (score 2):

To be on the safe side wait for RC.6, which will be the final release candidate.

Listen to this podcast where the Angular team members discuss RC.6:
https://devchat.tv/adv-in-angular/106-aia-angular2-rc5-and-beyond

Comment: Yakov I have yet to listen to the Podcast but doe they explicitly mention in that Podcast that RC6 will be the last release candidate?

Comment: They are not allowed to say this, but they hinted. BTW, upgrade from RC.5 to RC.6 went easy -  updated the config files only.